# Getting "EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" when installing chatterbot

Tags: python, pip, permission-denied, chatterbot

I get this error while installing chatterbot:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:  
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/attr'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Answer (score 0):

try installing with `pip install --user <package-name>`

Comment: i used this command pip install --user chatterbot  ,it install the chatterbot packege but when i try in python the it show again some error  >>> from chatterbot import ChatBot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'ChatBot' from 'chatterbot' (unknown location)